# How can a completion handler return to the wrong ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

We have a WebService singleton which handles all our API calls. All works fine unless we have multiple API calls at once from different ViewControllers.

1. VCA sends request A
2. VCB sends request B
3. Response B is returned to VCB
4. Response A is returned to VCA - this causes an exception

WebService:

```
typealias ServiceResponse = (NSDictionary!, NSError!) -> ()

class WebService: NSObject {

var serviceResponse : ServiceResponse!

class var sharedInstance:WebService {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = WebService()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}

func callWebserviceWith(paramsDict: NSDictionary, sendAccessToken: Bool, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) -> Void {
    serviceResponse = onCompletion
```

How can this happen?

Comment: *"this causes an exception"* - what kind? Having *any* state remembered in any singleton is a **very, very, very** bad idea. I do not really have to explain it any more because you have created the prime example here! `serviceResponse = onCompletion` will certainly cause you a ton of problems. What are you expecting to happen when to calls to `callWebserviceWith` happen close to each other?

Comment: why not use a different instance for each ViewController?

Comment: @luk2302 Uhu yep, we inherited this code and I am trying to under why this design pattern was selected and what might be the best approach to move to. The exception is simply caused by the response data not being the right structure.

Comment: @4oby Good question, it might causes issues for us elsewhere but we can resolve that as we had the same problem in the Android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with completion block, it's how you are dealing with it :)

**Mistake**

Your singleton ServiceResponse class has a class variable named serviceResponse that means there will be only one variable named serviceResponse in the memory (This is a pointer variable holding the reference to function pointer)

```
var serviceResponse : ServiceResponse!
```

Now when VCA makes a call it passes its pointer to block of code lets call VCAF1 now your serviceResponse will have value of VCAF1, assume that your web service is not yet complete and VCB calls the webservice and passes its pointer VCBf1 which is absolutely different from VCAF1 (differrent functions or blocks of code all together) but your serviceResponse is not bothered is it it simply forgets its early value and starts holding VCBf1.

Now your first service call response arrives and your code says execute the code for which I am holding reference in serviceResponse. Ta da!!!!! error :) You are executing wrong code :)

**Solution**

I dont find any problem in design to be honest but then I might be wrong :) Creating a singleton class for webservice is very common approach used, closures are nothing differrent then the blocks in objectiveC and I never had any issue with singleton design pattern through out my career as iOS developer :)

All you have to do

1. delete variable serviceResponse
2. modify the function to use function arguement rather than instance property

```
func callWebserviceWith(paramsDict: NSDictionary, sendAccessToken: Bool, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) -> Void {
    //when done use funtion arguement passed :)
    onCompletion()
}
```

Comment: This is much clearer thanks. The serviceResponse is being accessed from the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods so that's why is was added. We shall have to refactor the class to remove these but this is probably going to be our approach. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Leon, the approach suggested would work perfectly if block based API used for creating network connection(like Block based NSURLSession API). If you want to work with delegate pattern i think you cannot avoid storing the completion blocks.

Comment: @BangOperator absolute;y, we're working on that now as moving away from the singleton model causes another issue we can't tackle right now!

Comment: @leon : If you are working with delegates model then try to accept the delegate for your singleton WebService as well rather then messing with completion block and saving it buddy :) saving the reference to completion block will always lead to destruction :) Because you have multiple classes calling the WebService consider having multicast delegate then the normal delegate in WebService class then before calling the method of protocol try checking respondsToSelector for each delegate :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari woah, lots to research there! Thanks :D

Comment: @leon : And interesting too :) As there is no inbuilt support for multicast delegate in iOS but you will find many tutorials on it over the net :) Happy coding buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
VCA sends request A
VCB sends request B
Response B is returned to VCB
Response A is returned to VCA - this causes an exception
```

Since VCA and VCB uses same `callwebservicelwith` VCB updates VCA's completion block with completion block of VCB.

When VCB receives data, it is well sent to VCB, but then, when VCA's response is obtained, the completion block of VCB is called.

And I assume VCB is trying to parse data for VCA response, this causes the problem.

You need to re-achitect you model.

---

With minimal change in mind, you can scrap off the singleton and use different instances for different View Controllers.(as pointed by 4oy)

There are lots of third party lib to help you in this regard.